# Angular 5 switch to HttpClient broke my services

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable, angular5

Before Angular 5, we imported and used `Http` from `@angular/http`. Now we use `HttpClient` from `@angular/common/http`. There's some level of convenience added, because no we don't need the unnecessary step of turning all of our response data to JSON format every time we make a call using `.map(res => res.json())`. However, now we aren't suppose to use `.map`. We are suppose to go straight to `.subscribe()`. Again, this is suppose to be convenient. However, I used to do some logic in my services, where my API calls live, before returning the data to the subscribing functions in other components. For example,

The component:

```
getData(id) {
    this.service.getDataFromApi(id).subscribe(res => this.doSomething(res));
}
```

The service:

```
public getDataFromApi(id) {
    if (this.data.length > 0) {
        return Observable.of(this.data);
    } else {
        return this.http.get(this.apiPath + id)
            .map((response: any) => {
                this.data = response.json();
                return this.data;
            });
    }
}
```

Now, they suggest we shorten the service call to something like the following:

```
public getDataFromApi(id) {
    if (this.data.length > 0) {
        return Observable.of(this.data);
    } else {
        return this.http.get(this.apiPath + id);
    }
}
```

I am not suppose to use `.map` because it will no longer be supported in the future. How can I do some logic before returning the data? I don't want to make a call for some data that already exists and doesn't change. Multiple components are using this service. Am I suppose to turn every single service call into a raw promise and run some logic before resolving? If I were to just call subscribe right on the component's function, I wouldn't even need to have the service. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **can** use `map`. The new HttpClient has the added convenience of defaulting the response type to JSON, but it still returns an `Observable` -- and there are no plans to deprecate `map` from the Observable API.

So, your code only needs slight modification (take out the `.json()`):

```
public getDataFromApi(id) {
    if (this.data.length > 0) {
        return Observable.of(this.data);
    } else {
        return this.http.get(this.apiPath + id)
            .map((response: any) => {
                this.data = response;
                return this.data;
            });
    }
}
```

See the Observable API docs [here](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html).

Comment: if you want to "save" the result of a Observable, use "do", not "map". tecnically map is used when we can change the data

Answer (score 1):

If you use the new HttpClient, there is no res.json method. It will work automatically, just pass the response type like this:

```
return this.http.get(this.apiPath + id)
        .toPromise()
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data)
            return data
        });
```

Comment: So simple, but works perfectly. Naturally, I'm embarrassed, but thank you.

Comment: @Sajeetharan but you ignored his main question. You just convert Observable to Promise.